# ¿És posible crear un diagrama a partir de una tabla de excel variable?

Tags: excel, microsoft-office, tablas

Es decir a mi me llegan diferentes archivos excel que todos siguen el mismo formato pero no contienen el mismo contenido y uno puede que contenga mas contenido que otro etc.

Se tiene que realizar con una macro a un formato específico y luego exportarlo? Existe algún programa que lo realice automáticamente?

Ejemplo de dos tablas que podría recibir y el formato que luego quiero sacarlo en un diagrama.

[image: Imagen1]

Este es el diagrama de ejemplo de la primera tabla y seguiría el mismo formato para la segunda tabla.
[image: Imagen2]

Comment: Si lo necesitas con el formato exacto que muestras en tu imagen, es decir, insertando formas con texto, entonces sí, necesitas VBA si no quieres hacerlo a mano. Si el diseño visual es solo una idea, puedes resumir tus datos con una tabla dinámica, y ponerla en `Diseño de Informe -> Mostrar en forma de esquema`

Comment: Si el diagrama requiere un acabado profesional una opción sería generarlo en latex, [podrías generar el código de latex](http://texample.net/tikz/examples/rule-based-diagram/) a partir de cualquier lenguaje de programación como una impresión de texto... si esto lo vas a requerir siempre, otra opción sería usar [Lucidchart](https://www.lucidchart.com/) ellos permiten vincular sus diagramas a datos de [hojas de cálculo - Google Sheets](https://lucidchart.zendesk.com/hc/es-419/articles/115000403726-Vinculaci%C3%B3n-de-diagramas-Lucidchart-a-datos-de-hojas-de-c%C3%A1lculo)

Comment: Olvide aquí un sitio dónde puedes compilar [diagramas de latex](https://www.papeeria.com/p/7e8d82fd-f369-4afd-8d36-2c17240866c2#/main.tex)

Comment: Me pone que no existe el proyecto @HubertRonald

Comment: Esta es la página web [**Papperia**](https://www.papeeria.com/) sólo dale click a Live Demo y ya puedes compilar el código latex que escribas, pegues o que genere tu código.